# How to use Google Appscript to add up specific amount of values separated by names/emails?

Tags: javascript

While I was coding my project, I was stuck with this problem.

| Name/Email | Hour |
| --- | --- |
| Suzy | 5 |
| Michael | 2 |
| Michael | 6 |
| Suzy | 2 |
| Brandon | 1 |

How to make the script to print out or log their total hours specified by their emails/names whenever the function calls?

The result will be like

Suzy: 7
Michael: 8
Brandon: 1

I tried to set variables or functions to add up the total values, but none of them worked out and sent only errors.

Comment: Can we get a snippet of your current code? It would help to be able to modify it.